# Text not being italicized

Tags: support, status-bydesign, markdown

Using italics when answering a question is not showing correctly.

Select the text and click on the 'I', it comes out with asterisk and the selected text followed by another asterisk.

Am using Chrome Version 20.0.1132.47 (0) on Arch Linux.

The link to the answer I posted on the main site is [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25396/how-to-find-out-if-my-devices-kernel-has-loop-device-support#comment30638_25399). (I know, its linked to the comment, as there's no direct way of linking to the answer - feature request?)

Anyone else notice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both underscores and asterisks work for italics, it has nothing at all to do with the button.  Basically you've confused the parser that converts the Markdown to HTML.

You have to escape the underscore with a backslash: `*kernel\_config.gz*`

Which shows as: *kernel_config.gz*

Comment: Ahhh... Cheers mate for that :) Gotcha... so the parser is slighty..."out by one" :P